# how to create a snapshot using Xcode 7?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, snapshot, xcode7

I can create snapshot in Xcode 6 this way as shown in below image:

[image: Xcode 6]

But in Xcode 7 its not available and you can see that in below Image:

[image: Xcode 7]

And `control-command-S` also doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me now how can I create a snapshot using Xcode 7?

Comment: Have you tried searching 'snapshot' from the help menu?

Comment: @kmcgrady thanks for your suggestion, I will test it and tell you the result..:)

Comment: Note that Xcode 7 is still under NDA. The right way to go about your problem would be to post it in the Apple Developer Forums (if you think that you're simply not finding something) or file a Radar (if you believe it to be a bug).

Comment: While I wouldn't call it a solution for this question: I really do urge you to learn git. Xcode Snapshots themselves are based on it and it does a lot more for you.

Comment: I know git very well and thanks for your suggestion Tim.

Comment: @TimBodeit Is it definitely under NDA? AFAIK last year they didn't NDA the new iOS/Mac OS. I was pretty sure it was the same with Xcode.

Comment: @kmcgrady They lifted the NDA on certain aspects of "technical information", because they are publicly sharing most recordings of WWDC Sessions [online](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/). All pre-release software including the iOS, Mac OS and Xcode binaries remains under NDA. I would usually assume, that everything that I need to log into the developer portal for is under NDA. Everything that Apple shares publicly is not.

Comment: @kmcgrady For the record, there are no longer any menu items containing the word "snapshot". The only results from searching in Help are pages from the  documentation.

Answer (score 17):

I opened a bug regarding this.  According to Apple, "Snapshots have been removed in Xcode 7. You can export existing snapshots in Xcode 7 but not create or restore them."

Hopefully they'll restore them in a future release, but for now I recommend using git from the Source Control menu as suggested by Tim.

Answer (score 1):

there isn't snapshot in xcode 7, to resolve this problem, use xcode 6 and 7, xcode 6 to create and restore snapshot and after you can open your project with xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity - in the menu at the top select "SourceControl" then "Commit...", add a comment and "Commit X Files" then after you make additional changes and want to see the changes select "SourceControl" and "Commit" and select the file on the left.

All explained nicely in :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7